# How to set jumbo frames on an unmanaged switch?

Tags: switch, jumbo-frames

I'm using industrial cameras via the GigE interface.  I just purchased a NETGEAR  8-port unmanaged PoE switch, specifically model number GS108LP.

If I connect multiple cameras to the switch and then read frames from a computer I'm getting some frame grab errors.  If I only use one camera I don't get any frame grab errors.

The frame size in the cameras and my computer is set to 1500.  I'm pretty sure the resolution to the frame drop concern is I need to set jumbo frames (ex. frame size 3000, 4096, 6000, or 8192) for the computer, camera, and switch.

The computer and camera are an easy change, however I'm not sure how to set jumbo frames in the switch.  It seems the Netgear Insight application requires a subscription which I don't have, and would rather not pay for just this one use.  Also, I'm not sure if Netgear Insight works with an "unmanaged" switch.  Does "unmanaged" mean that configuration software won't work with a switch?  How can I get jumbo frames on the switch?  Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't; that's why it's called "unmanaged" – it has no management or configuration facilities.<sup>1</sup>

(But if it were a managed switch, it would normally provide direct configuration access through its built-in HTTP or SSH or Telnet service (just like home routers do) – hopefully without needing any cloud services.)

Each switch – managed or not – has a physical maximum frame size which it can accept. Managed switches usually let you raise the limit *up to* that maximum, unmanaged switches just always work at the maximum size they can work with.

The manufacturer's web page for GS108LP (although oddly not its data sheet) says the maximum frame size for this switch is 10000 bytes – so there is nothing you need to do here.

---

<sup>1</sup> With the odd exception of TP-Link's "Unmanaged Pro" series, the name of which is a blatant lie.